# Brian Goetz on 'final' keyword

Tags: java, final

In this article: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp1029/index.html

Brian Goetz states: "Just because class X is compiled against final class Y doesn't mean that the same version of class Y will be loaded at run time."

Could someone please explain this in more detail? If class Y is final, it can't be subclassed, so what's the meaning of this statement?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose you load a class X with a classloader that has a *different* implementation of class Y. In that case, X would be linked with the different Y.

Note that the statement says "the same **version** of class Y", which means Y could simply be changed after X was compiled.

Comment: Y could have also been changed before X was compiled.  The difference is what was on the classpath during compilation vs. runtime.

Answer (score 1):

If X is compiled against class Y thats in jar Z you can run class X with class V in jar W

its similar to compiling a class in java 1.5 but running it in 1.6

Answer (score 1):

What is being stated is not that the class can be subclassed. But rather that you have no guarantee of the version of the built class that you are running against.  You could make some change, recompile and swap the binaries out. Your code would run but it would be a different version.